# CUDA Neural Network Simulation

Tags: c, cuda, neural-network, nvidia

I have to simulate Neural Network in `CUDA` but I don't know much about this technology. Where should I start?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These questions aren't well-suited on SO, but I'm posting a few resources you might start with anyway

- The "*Learning CUDA*" section of the NVIDIA website is the best spot on resources and tutorials to get you up to speed: https://developer.nvidia.com/how-to-cuda-c-cpp
- [CUDA by Example](https://developer.nvidia.com/content/cuda-example-introduction-general-purpose-gpu-programming-0)(beginner) and [Programming Massively Parallel Processors](https://developer.nvidia.com/content/programming-massively-parallel-processors-hands-approach) (intermediate) are also two good resources targeted to novices and intermediate CUDA users. There are lots more on the subject in the "Books" section of the NVIDIA website.
- Once you got familiar with the basics of CUDA I recommend studying the [CUDA SDK samples](https://developer.nvidia.com/gpu-computing-sdk).

Regarding AI topics (I suppose "Network" means "Neural Network") there are some academic papers and lectures you might start with, but those would prove useless if you don't have a CUDA background first.

Comment: Marco, you are right, it is a Neural Network. Thank you for all the above info, I am sure they would be very useful.  One more question, where I can take some example for a crush introduction on this topic(Neural Network/Network Simulation)?

Comment: A definitely not-crash course would be the (slightly out-date) Russell-Norwig (http://aima.cs.berkeley.edu/) book, but for a quicker primer you could use one of the codeproject.com tutorials, pick one which received a good rating and seems comprehensible to you.

Comment: Ciao Marco, I am currently learning CUDA but what I need to do eventually is "spiking neural network simulation implelented in CUDA" but with my own code, without using any extisitng library. What do you suggest me to do? Also, Can I email you?